# Autowired dependencies failed in spring-mvc Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

i tried to run an application in spring MVC and Hibernate using Netbeans. The flow is that i'm passing an ajax request to the controller and i'm getting the
response to jsp page without adding @Autowired and Dao(ie, a plain method returning a string from controller).
But while adding @Autowired annotation and calling employeeDao i'm getting the below error(ie, unable to autowire) .
i have given the right package in the applicationContext.xml(com.demo) and also tried with  but still getting 
the same error. Can anyone please help me. Many Thanks in advance....
`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "getServices",
    data:  {optionsvalue:optionsvalue},
    success: function(data) {
      $("#idServices").html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Unable to fetch Services");
    }

});
```

Here is the EmployeeController.java
`

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
   @Autowired
   EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getServices", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getServices(HttpServletRequest request){
        List<ProductServices> pdtServices = employeeDao.getAllServices(request.getParameter("optionsvalue")==null?"":request.getParameter("optionsvalue"));
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int i=0;
        for(ProductServices ps : pdtServices){
     i++;
         strBuilder.append("<td>");
         strBuilder.append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"chkService"+i+" value="+ps.getServices()+">"+ps.getServices()+"<br>");
         strBuilder.append("</td>");
         strBuilder.append("<td>");
         strBuilder.append("<input class=\"form-control col-xs-1\" name=\"accountNo"+i+" id=\"accountNo\" required=\"true\" placeholder=\"Acc no\" type=\"text\">");
         strBuilder.append("</td>");
         strBuilder.append("<td>");
         strBuilder.append("<input class=\"form-control col-xs-1\" name=\"transactionLimit"+i+" id=\"transactionLimit\" required=\"true\" placeholder=\"Transaction limit\" type=\"text\">");
         strBuilder.append("</td>");
         strBuilder.append("</tr>");
        }
    return strBuilder.toString();
    }
 }
```

Here is EmployeeDao.java

```
@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    private Session session;
    public List<ProductServices> getAllServices(String strProductId){
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProductServices.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("productId", strProductId));
        return (List<ProductServices>) cr.list();
    }

   }
```

This is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.*"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <!-- Data Source Declaration for Hibernate-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demo.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.minpool}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.maxpool}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>           
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and i'm getting the error like this

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.demo.dao.employeeDao com.demo.controller.employeeController.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.Session com.demo.dao.employeeDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.Session] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:547)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1485)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:368)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.demo.dao.employeeDao com.demo.controller.employeeController.employeeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.Session com.demo.dao.employeeDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.Session] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.Session com.demo.dao.employeeDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.Session] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.Session com.demo.dao.employeeDaoImpl.session; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.Session] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.Session] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 73 more
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to see without knowing what's in your applicationContext.xml. But the exception says that there is no "Session" class object to inject. Make sure spring is initializing this object. Or if it is infact true that your DAO method should set the session itself, remove the @Autowired annotation from the field

Comment: Hi, your session is autowired, but in the method "getAllServices" you set this property with "session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();" ?
Then perhaps the autowired for the session property is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just delete @Autowired from Session object. You get session from session factory.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `@Autowired` from the `Session`, and declare it inside of the method

```
@Repository("employeeDao")
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<ProductServices> getAllServices(String strProductId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProductServices.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("productId", strProductId));
        return (List<ProductServices>) cr.list();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following code

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public List<ProductServices> getAllServices(String strProductId){
        Criteria cr = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ProductServices.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("productId", strProductId));
        return (List<ProductServices>) cr.list();
    }

}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: i have  changed the code as above but still same exception.